# Why are my stove's burners releasing gas and sparking but not igniting?

Tags: gas, oven, stove

This seems to be an occasional problem. I turn one of the burners to light and I can smell the gas and I can see the flickering of the spark and hear the clicking, but the burner never ignites.

What is strangest about this is that when it occurs it occurs on all four burners. Strangely, at least this time, the oven is still working.

Comment: Could be a bad fuel air mixture, do you have enough oxygen in your house? Do you feel lightheaded, dizzy, nauseous, or disoriented?

Comment: It does start giving me a headache and I turn it off so that it stops...I think the issue may be correlated to whether the oven is on...if the oven is on, this seems to occur.

Comment: If it happens *only* when the oven is on, it could be that the supply pressure is low, the supply tubing is undersized, or there's a restriction on the supply tubing. If you're getting lightheaded waiting for the burners to ignite, you might consider opening some windows or tuning on an exhaust fan.

Comment: 1: Buy a butane lighter and keep it near the stove. An empty one'll work in a pinch, you just need the spark. 2: Is your stove level? Gas flows through channels or tubes from the burner to the ignitor. If the stove's not level, most of it can flow the wrong way. Having a warm cooktop, as when the oven is on, can push leveling related ignition problems over the edge into nonfunctionality.

Answer (score 1):

Clean all the tubes in your gas burners. You might have baked on gunk blocking an opening, or even a spider egg case. Spider nests are a huge problem in outside BBQ gas grills. 
It's one reason why I no longer use gas BBQ grills.