# Brand new stove burners won't light

Tags: gas, stove, natural-gas, range, gas-burner

I have a brand new [Samsung NX58H5600 series free-standing gas range](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/freestanding-gas-ranges-nx58h5600-series) with five stovetop burners. The unique oval-shaped center burner works without issue.

[image: center burner with blue flames]

But none of the four "normal" burners will light. I see a spark at each burner and smell gas when I try to get the burners to light, but nothing happens.

[image: one of four standard circle burners on stovetop]
[image: a silver cavity under a stovetop burner plate]

I've tried waiting for several seconds for any of these four burners to light, but they never do. Am I missing something? Is there a trick, or perhaps the installers failed to do something here? I understand that [obstructions in the gas line](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62681/why-are-my-stoves-burners-releasing-gas-and-sparking-but-not-igniting) could cause an issue, or perhaps a [faulty gas valve](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/156732/why-wont-one-of-my-gas-stoves-burners-ignite), but I thought that seemed odd since this is brand new.

Although there's a bit of debris on the stovetop as seen in the photos, that only happened just now as I captured these photos and dropped something near the stove. It *was* perfectly clean as I've been trying to get it working over the past several days, which makes it seem odd a gas line would already be obstructed by gunk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My KitchenAid (just took it apart for cleaning, so this is fresh in my mind) looks nearly identical (except the oval burner - but instead it has a 2-section round burner) with the empty section underneath, metal part with teeth on top and burner cap on top. Without everything in place you get sparks & gas but not ignition. When I got my current cooktop it was a Sears outlet special (incredible deal) but turned out to be missing one of the caps (they grabbed the parts off another, so no problem) so those caps may be missing or sitting in a box somewhere. They look something like this:

[image]

On a mid-to-high end cooktop, you will typically find that each burner will be a slightly different size (physical dimensions and BTU), so you have to make sure the caps are correct - if they are not correct then they will not stay on very well and the burner will either not light at all or not burn correctly.

Comment: Thanks! You are absolutely correct. Once I found and placed these caps on the burners they immediately worked